# Getting started with vue-resource

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, vue.js

Struggling to find any pre-made examples of use for the vue-resource plugin of vue.js, I tried this :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.12.7/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/0.1.13/vue-resource.min.js"></script>

<div id="my_view">
  <p>{{ origin }}</p>
</div>

<script>
var Vue = require('vue');
Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));

new Vue({
    el: '#my_view',
    data: {
       origin: ''
    },

    ready: function() {

        // GET request
        this.$http.get('http://httpbin.org/ip', function (data, status, request) {

            // set data on vm
            this.$set('origin', data)

        }).error(function (data, status, request) {
            // handle error
        })
      }
})
</script>
```

to just query [httpbin.org/ip](http://httpbin.org/ip) (a random REST endpoint i could find) and display the result inside `#myview > p`. It's just the example (an adapted version) provided on the [vue-resource github page](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource) that I'm trying to run.

Can anyone see what I'm not getting right to achieve this ?

Edit: added comma, and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nmarshall/dccbbkam/) is the fiddle of it.

Comment: Any syntax or other errors in the javascript console? There's a comma missing before "ready". Can help further if you turn this into a fiddle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its because you are using `require`. If you use `require` you need some lib like http://browserify.org/

This example is now working:
http://jsfiddle.net/dccbbkam/2/

And here is another example for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/dccbbkam/4/

Comment: Thanks ! no need to precise I'm starting with javascript, I think you spotted that already :)